# Render a single string of latex and html content in React/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, latex

I have a string that contains HTML content and latex equations.
I can use react-latex-next to parse the latex content and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for the HTML content.

```
<div className="text-lg mt-5">
    <Latex>{latextString}</Latex>
</div>
<p
  className="mt-2.5 text-lg"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: htmlString,
  }}
></p>
```

Is there a way to parse both HTML and LaTeX while passing it as a string variable?

e.g. If I had a string that started with some HTML content (paragraph tags, line breaks etc.) followed by latexString.

Is there a way to parse both HTML and LaTeX by passing it as a variable?

I have tried the above-mentioned methods and want to know if there are other better approaches to it. Currently, they work separately. The problem occurs when the latext string is part of htmlstring, it doesn't render then.